# Importing data from excel using a struct in Matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, struct

I want to import an excel spreadsheet into matlab. Here is what I want specifically, I would like to create a struct with 26 fields a field for each of the column headers and then the data for the field be the respective data in the matching column. I know the ranges for the data.

```
spect importdata('filename.xlsx') returns this
spect =   
      data: [256x26 struct]
  textdata: [1x26 struct]
colheaders: [1x26 struct]
```

I want to be able to divide up the data part into 26 different 256x1 struct fields. For example. Can anyone help me with this?

```
row: [256x1 struct]
col: [256x1 struct]
...
Cho: [256x1 struct]
textdata: [1x26 struct]
colheaders: [1x26 struct]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to split the columns of the array of structures `spect.data` into separate arrays?

This is how you can do it

```
%# define new field names
newFields = {'row','col','Cho'}; %# and all the rest

%# loop through new fields to assign columns of spect.data
for i=1:length(newFields)
   spect.(newFields{i}) = spect.data(:,i);
end

%# remove .data from spect
spect = rmfield(spect,'data');
```

Comment: Thats mostly what I am looking for but I still want to be able to able to access each individual element in the spect fields. for example spect{i}.row

Comment: @Ben Fossen: Would `spect(i).row` give you what you want?

Comment: No it does not it gives all the elements in the list when you do spect(1).row and spect(2).row exceeds the matrix dimensions.

Comment: I figured it out I needed to do spect.row(i)

Comment: @Ben: Oops, sorry, I mistyped. Glad you figured it out yourself.